# Are accepted answers pinned to the top in Ask Ubuntu Meta?

Tags: support, meta

I was going through Ask Ubuntu Meta and found this question: [Bullying as a strategy to force close a question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16530). There are 2 answers to the question: [one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16542) by [Zanna](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) and [one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16541) by [karel](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/94914/karel).

I used the sort answers by votes feature. Our community [decided](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19733) that accepted answers would be pinned to the top instead of the post with the highest score in Ask Ubuntu Meta.

But, in karel's meta question, Zanna's answer was pinned to the top. Is this because of the the sort answers by votes feature or is this a bug? I have no clue. Please help me understand the situation.

Comment: @muru That question did not have any answer. I have added one answer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As muru indirectly pointed out, this is because karel accepted their own answer. When a person accepts their own answer it is not pinned to the top. This behaviour is longstanding (it has been that way on both meta and main at least since I joined in 2016).

[Here's an example](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11988/527764) of a post where the accepted answer is pinned above a slightly more popular one.